# Brand New Nail Gun Makes a Dent but No Nails Come Out

Tags: nails

I just got a Blue Hawk air compressor and nail gun combo. I have added oil, I'm using 18 ga 5/8" nails and when I press the trigger a dent shoots into the wood but no nails.  I called support and they were unable to help me.  Any ideas?  Is it just defective?

Comment: I think the dent is just the nail gun's impact against the surface by a combination of either 1) the pressure you're pressing against it and/or 2) recoil

Comment: What is the model number of the gun?

Comment: Dent means the hammer is moving, but something's blocking the nail from feeding into position.

Comment: Are you sure you loaded the nails correctly if there is no tension on the nails there is nothing to move them under the striker.

Answer (score 7):

## Check the pressure

Check the recommended pressure range listed on the gun, and make sure the compressor is putting out a pressure within that range. I've seen similar symptoms when the pressure was too low.  Presumably the hammer didn't have enough energy to move the nail, so it skipped over it instead.

## Properly load the nails

If the nails are not properly loaded, they may not be fed into the line of the hammer. You'll end up just firing the hammer into the wood, instead of a nail.

## Engage the feeder

Make sure the nail feeding mechanism is in place. If it's not, the nails will not be fed into the line of the hammer. This again will lead to you firing the hammer, instead of a nail.

## Nail compatibility

Insure that the nails are compatible with the gun. If they're not, the gun may not fire, misfire, or self destruct.

Comment: If it is making a "big" dent then it usually means that your nails are jammed.  Your nails should be pushed all the way to the bottom and then you should make sure the spring is engaged.  If the nails aren't compatible this should be apparent when you open up the gun - the first nail will be angled or jammed.  If it is just "jamming" on you I would definitely take it back since the problem will just get worse.  I would add too with the cheaper guns that sometime they pop but not shoot when you aren't pressing down hard enough - I have never used Blue Hawk so not sure but it is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that specific gun, but it sounds like the spring that pushes the nails into the "chamber" isn't working. Either it's broken/defective, or the gun somehow allows you to put the nails in wrong (which seems unlikely).

Take it back and see what the next one does.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I checked the pressure, and knew the nails were compatible and what seemed to be properly loaded. Looking closely into where the nails feed, I noticed a nail was jammed up right at the top inside the feeder. I was able to open the top of the nail feeder and remove the jammed nail. Now the gun works properly again! This may be your issue. If not continue troubleshooting with above suggestions. Make sure to note if it is an oil free finish nail gun as I have a newer Rigid model that is oil free.